# YT Members API for new Membership alerts?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Any advice on how to use the Members API (or any API) for new Member alerts on a live stream? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/members

On other services, we'd subscribe to an endpoint and listen for events. I haven't spotted anything similar here for YT - but totally possible I missed it.

I see other apps like Streamlabs can do the alerts, so I assume they are using something that exists?

Thanks for any help!

Searched for endpoints or any kind of documentation relating to Memberships API for Youtube - nothing looked similar to what might be used on Twitch.

Comment: Are you aware of any YouTube UI webpage receiving such subscription events pushed by YouTube servers (i.e. without refreshing the webpage, thanks to AJAX or WebSocket)? If so, please provide such a webpage URL.

Comment: Closest I have is a 3rd party service that provides a private URL - but after speaking with other parties, it looks like the route is not the Membership API but the Messages API - which should provide ... basically every event that happens in chat. So we're going to take a crack at filtering that to get what we need. If we get that working, I'll update this post so hopefully it helps others.

Comment: Also I appreciate the response Benjamin!